# Python: How to let the user input their own solution to the answer key

Tags: python, loops, testing

I have developed a test and I want to make it so the user can input their own answers to the test before the test actually starts. Here is what I have so far. Would it be better if I used a dictionary instead of doing raw input multiple times or is there a way I could just ask the user for their answers without doing that. Thanks!

```
ready = raw_input("Are you ready to do the test?(Please enter YES/NO) ")

while ready.lower() != "yes":
    ready = raw_input("Are you ready to do the test?(Please enter YES/NO) ")

if ready.lower() == "yes":
    print "Excelent! The test will start in any second."
if ready.lower() == "no":
    print "Okay, tell me when you're ready. "
elif ready.lower() != "yes" and "no":
    print "It okay if your're not sure. The test can start in any time you want. "

count = 0


if ready.lower() == "yes":
    question1 = raw_input("\nQuestion 1\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question1.lower() == "b":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question1.lower() != "b":
    print "Wrong"

question2 = raw_input("\nQuestion 2\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question2.lower() == "d":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question2.lower() != "d":
    print "Wrong"

question3 = raw_input("\nQuestion 3\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
    if question3.lower() == "a":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question3.lower() != "a":
    print "Wrong"

question4 = raw_input("\nQuestion 4\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question4.lower() == "a":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question4.lower() != "a":
    print "Wrong"

question5 = raw_input("\nQuestion 5\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question5.lower() == "c":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question5.lower() != "c":
    print "Wrong"

question6 = raw_input("\nQuestion 6\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question6.lower() == "a":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question6.lower() != "a":
    print "Wrong"

question7 = raw_input("\nQuestion 7\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question7.lower() == "b":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question7.lower() != "b":
    print "Wrong"

question8 = raw_input("\nQuestion 8\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question8.lower() == "a":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question8.lower() != "a":
    print "Wrong"

question9 = raw_input("\nQuestion 9\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question9.lower() == "c":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question9.lower() != "c":
    print "Wrong"

question10 = raw_input("\nQuestion 10\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question10.lower() == "d":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question10.lower() != "d":
    print "Wrong"

question11 = raw_input("\nQuestion 11\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question11.lower() == "b":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question11.lower() != "b":
    print "Wrong"

question12 = raw_input("\nQuestion 12\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question12.lower() == "c":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question12.lower() != "c":
    print "Wrong"

question13 = raw_input("\nQuestion 13\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question13.lower() == "d":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question13.lower() != "d":
    print "Wrong"

question14 = raw_input("\nQuestion 14\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question14.lower() == "a":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question14.lower() != "a":
    print "Wrong"

question15 = raw_input("\nQuestion 15\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question15.lower() == "a":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question15.lower() != "a":
    print "Wrong"

question16 = raw_input("\nQuestion 16\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question16.lower() == "c":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question16.lower() != "c":
    print "Wrong"

question17 = raw_input("\nQuestion 17\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question17.lower() == "c":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question17.lower() != "c":
    print "Wrong"

question18 = raw_input("\nQuestion 18\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question18.lower() == "b":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question18.lower() != "b":
    print "Wrong"

question19 = raw_input("\nQuestion 19\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question19.lower() == "d":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question19.lower() != "d":
    print "Wrong"

question20 = raw_input("\nQuestion 20\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ")
if question20.lower() == "a":
    print "Correct"
    count = count + 1
elif question20.lower() != "a":
    print "Wrong"

print "\n|Congratulation!,", "You have completed the test."
print "|Here's your result."
print "|Total score: " + str(count) + "/20"
division = float(count)/float(20)
multiply = float(division*100)
result = round(multiply)
print "|Total percentage is", int(result), "%"

if result >= 75:
    print ("|Congratulations, you have passed!")

elif result <= 70:
    print ("|Sorry, you have failed.\n|You should study more.")
```

**updated**: thank you I got the loop part down. Now I just need to know how I can allow the user to input their own answers to the test as well. To clarify, by this I mean allow the user to input their own answer key to the test and then begin the test.

```
answers = ["b", "d", "a", "a", "c", "a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a", "c", "c", "b", "d", "a"]

count = 0
for i in range(20):
    answer = raw_input("\nQuestion " + str(i+1) + "\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ");
    if answer.lower() == answers[i]:
        print "Correct"
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print "Wrong"
```

Comment: You should use **Classes**, learn from [Classes -- Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#classes)

Comment: @Anzel could you show an example please?

Comment: sure! see my answer, it's not the best but should really get you started, and learn how to use a class to solve similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loops are just created to avoid from this coding.  --kidding.

You can create an answers list where the correct choices are kept.
Then you can iterate over the questions with a `for` loop. 
Here is an example:

```
answers = ["b", "d", "a", "a", "c", "a"]

count = 0
for i in range(len(answers)):
    answer = raw_input("\nQuestion " + str(i+1) + "\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ");
    if answer.lower() == answers[i]:
        print "Correct"
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print "Wrong"
```

Comment: alright. sorry im a new coder. how to get loop to repeat to 20 and to continue saying question 1, question 2, etc. also how do i make it so the user can input their own answers as well.

Comment: `range` function does this for you. You just need to specify the upper limit. In your case, `for i in range(20):`. Keep in mind that, you also need to have an `answers` list with length of 20.

Comment: thank you! would you know how to let the user put in their own results?

Comment: Andrew, by result you mean answers right...? you are already doing that with your raw_input statement...

Comment: @blackwind by this i mean allowing the user to input their own set of solutions as right now i have inputed my set of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use 2d lists along with for loop, using Dict will not maintain the order of question, other wise you might want to use ordered Dict...

in 2d list you can write down question as well as its answers

```
questions = [["\nQuestion {0}\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ","b"],
             ["\nQuestion {0}\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ","d"],
             ["\nQuestion {0}\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ","a"],
             ["\nQuestion {0}\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ","c"],
             ["\nQuestion {0}\nWhat is your answer?\n \nA\nB\nC\nD\n\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ","d"]]

count=0

for n,i in enumerate(questions):
    quest = raw_input(i[0].format(n))
    if quest.lower() == i[1]:
        print "Correct"
        count = count + 1
    elif quest.lower() != i[1]:
        print "Wrong"
```

Comment: im sorry i dont quite get what you did here. could you please explain?

Comment: questions is 2d list  [ [quest1,ans1] , [ques2, ans2], [ques3,ans3]... [ques20,ans20]]


enumerate will feed for loop with current item and its order number which will be displayed as below [note the {0} in the list ] 
question 1
question2
question3...so on


learn more about format form python documentation it will be your friend in future :)

for more clarification run this code snippet...

Comment: got it thank you! any chance you know how to allow the user to input their own correct solution to the questions as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **Class**. Here is a quick mock up based on what you've got so far, it's more flexible, and reusable too. Think of you have different sets of questions for different grades, it's not a complete one but will get you started.

I have also put some comments and hopefully the code is self-explanatory:

```
class Questions:
    def __init__(self, title='', answers=[]):
        # title can then be changed to whatever you like (A,B,C,D,E,F... etc.)
        self.title = title
        # answers will be a python list, just like you have now
        self.answers = answers
        # we use a dictionary to store question N and its correct answer
        self.questions = {}
        # no of questions answered correctly
        self.count = 0
        # a boolean flag whether the test has been completed
        self.completed = False
        # check if answers are set, then loop through the list and set the key/value pair
        if self.answers:
            for i, answer in enumerate(self.answers):
                self.questions['Question ' + str(i+1)] = answer

    def start(self):
        if not self.answers:
            print "No question and answer set yet"
            return
        # you only need a YES answer, so set a while loop to break only on YES
        while raw_input('Are you ready to do the test? (Please enter YES/NO) ').lower() != 'yes':
            pass
        # reset the count in case people break in the middle of the questions
        self.count = 0
        # just iterate the list, and get the key/value pair as a question
        for i, answer in enumerate(self.answers):
            question = 'Question ' + str(i+1)
            ans = raw_input(question +'\n' + self.title)
            if ans.lower() == self.questions[question]:
                print "Correct"
                self.count += 1
            # quite obvious, if not Correct, that's Wrong
            else:
                print "Wrong"
        # once all questions answered, set completed flag as True
        self.completed = True
        # now go to get_result to print all stats you want
        return self.get_result()

    def get_result(self):
        # to check if all questions are actually completed
        if not self.completed:
            print "You still haven't completed the test yet"
            return
        print "\n|Congratulation!,", "You have completed the test."
        print "|Here's your result."
        print "|Total score: " + str(self.count) + "/20"
        division = float(self.count)/float(20)
        multiply = float(division*100)
        result = round(multiply)
        print "|Total percentage is", int(result), "%"
        if result <= 70:
            print ("|Sorry, you have failed.\n|You should study more.")
        # well again, if result is not <=70, it will be above.
        else:
            print ("|Congratulations, you have passed!")
```

Usage:

```
# set the title so do not repeat yourself on each question asked
# and the answers will be a list of the Correct answer, you get the idea
myquestions = Questions(title='What is your answer?\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ', answers=['b','d','a','c','a','b','a','c','d','b','c','d','a','c','c','b','d','a'])

# After you instantiated your class, the __init__ is called, and so the questions dictionary is created automatically
 myquestions.questions
{'Question 1': 'b',
 'Question 10': 'b',
 'Question 11': 'c',
 'Question 12': 'd',
 'Question 13': 'a',
 'Question 14': 'c',
 'Question 15': 'c',
 'Question 16': 'b',
 'Question 17': 'd',
 'Question 18': 'a',
 'Question 2': 'd',
 'Question 3': 'a',
 'Question 4': 'c',
 'Question 5': 'a',
 'Question 6': 'b',
 'Question 7': 'a',
 'Question 8': 'c',
 'Question 9': 'd'}
```

To start your test, call `myquestions.start()`

```
myquestions.start()
Are you ready to do the test? (Please enter YES/NO) yes

Question 1
What is your answer?

A
B
C
D
Please enter A, B, C or D: b
Correct

...

Question 18
What is your answer?

A
B
C
D
Please enter A, B, C or D: s
Wrong

|Congratulation!, You have completed the test.
|Here's your result.
|Total score: 1/20
|Total percentage is 5 %
|Sorry, you have failed.
|You should study more.
```

At the completion of all questions, the `get_result` will be called and print your stats.

My code is not really optimized, but this should really get you to understand how to use **Class** to solve any similar problems you have in future.

Comment: thank you, i just dont understand the code but at what part does this code does it ask the user to input their own solutions to the questions.

Comment: @Andrew, this => `myquestions = Questions(title='What is your answer?\nPlease enter A, B, C or D: ', answers=['b','d','a','c','a','b','a','c','d','b','c','d','a','c','c','b','d','a'])`